# Read-only list or unmodifiable list in .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, java, .net, readonly-collection

From what I can tell, .NET 4.0 still lacks read-only lists. Why does the framework still lack this functionality? Isn't this one of the commonest pieces of functionality for [domain-driven design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-driven_design)?

One of the few advantages Java has over C# is this in the form of the [Collections.unmodifiablelist(list)](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) method, which it seems is long overdue in IList<T> or List<T>.

Using `IEnumerable<T>` is the easiest solution to the question - `ToList` can be used and returns a copy.

Comment: Seems like the only real way to have a true read only `List<T>` is to write your own, there is no built in class that I know of that supports all of the "read only" features of `List<T>` out of the box like `Contains`, LINQ queries, etc.

Answer (score 156, accepted):

You're looking for [`ReadOnlyCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx), which has been around since .NET2.

```
IList<string> foo = ...;
// ...
ReadOnlyCollection<string> bar = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(foo);
```

or

```
List<string> foo = ...;
// ...
ReadOnlyCollection<string> bar = foo.AsReadOnly();
```

This creates a read-only *view*, which reflects changes made to the wrapped collection.

Comment: I feel a bit stupid having asked this question now - and not known about ReadOnlyCollection

Comment: don't be - neither did I, when I went looking for the same thing and found Your question

Comment: That's an annoyingly hard class to find. It's in the System.Collections.ObjectModel namespace instead of System.Collections.Generic where I would expect to find it. I suppose it's because that's where it was before the Generic namespace existed. Still I would expect the base class to remain in ObjectModel and the generic class to be added to Generic. I suppose they had their reasons, but I find it annoying.

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection is still user editable, the Items property retrieves the base list, and you can then use standard Add/Remove functions on the base list?

Comment: @BlueMonkMN : Please refer this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kcwalina/archive/2005/03/15/396086.aspx) to find out why it's seperate from the Collections.Generic namespace.

Comment: But that's not a List, it's a Collection. So if you use it, you need to modify all your code to use Collection instead of List.

Comment: Why it doesn't provide linq capabilities like Where or FirstOrDefault? Neither does IReadOnlyList.

Comment: @AlirezaAhmadiRad Also, neither the interface or `ReadOnlyCollection` has methods like `Contains`, it's a bit disappointing.

Comment: Further to comment above by Uchitha, the "article" has a new link, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/kcwalina/the-reason-why-collection-readonlycollection-and-keyedcollection-were-moved-to-system-collections-objectmodel-namespace

Answer (score 14):

For those who like to use interfaces: 
.NET 4.5 adds the generic [`IReadOnlyList`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlylist-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) interface which is implemented by `List<T>` for example.

It is similar to [`IReadOnlyCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ireadonlycollection-1?view=netframework-4.7.2) and adds an `Item` indexer property.

Answer (score 13):

How about the [ReadOnlyCollection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.objectmodel.readonlycollection-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) already within the framework?

Answer (score 11):

If the most common pattern of the list is to iterate through all the elements, `IEnumerable<T>` or `IQueryable<T>` can effectively act as a read-only list as well.

Comment: If you expose your List as an IEnumerable, then the consumer could simply cast it back to List and modify it.

Comment: Of course, but it's not intended to be a bulletproof measure - you could also probably read the private fields and track down the original list. It's more as describing the intent that this should stay read-only.

Comment: You're not modifying the original list by calling `ToList()` either, just a copy

Comment: Note that `IEnumerable` is not a complete set of "read only" methods, for example it does not contain methods like `Contains`.

Answer (score 8):

In 2.0 you can call `AsReadOnly` to get a read-only version of the list. Or wrap an existing `IList` in a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` object.

Comment: that's the equivalent of Collections.unmodifiablelist(list) I was after

Comment: I missed this in .NET 4 because I was using an IList<T> instead of a true List<T>. Make sure to notice that AsReadOnly is still available in .NET 4 so long as you're dealing with a a List<T>.

Answer (score 7):

What's wrong with [System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Create an extension method ToReadOnlyList() on IEnumerable, then

```
IEnumerable<int> ints = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
var intsReadOnly = ints.ToReadOnlyList();
//intsReadOnly [2]= 9; //compile error, readonly
```

here is the extension method

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static IReadOnlyList<T> ToReadOnlyList<T>(this IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        IReadOnlyList<T> rol = items.ToList();
        return rol;
    }
}
```

see [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32433514/2055187) too