# Unmodifiable lists in C#

Tags: c#, .net, collections, c#-4.0, unmodifiable

In Java, one can use the Collections#unmodifiableList() method to create an unmodifiable list from an existing List object.  Is there any counterpart in C# ? I'm new to the language and haven't been able to find anything like this in the MSDN docs.

Comment: Net framework offers that
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984042/unmodifiablelist-in-net-4-0

Comment: There are quite a few questions covering this, including: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326574/properly-exposing-a-listt

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[ReadOnlyCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx)

```
var dinosaurs = new List<string>();

dinosaurs.Add("Tyrannosaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Amargasaurus");
dinosaurs.Add("Deinonychus");
dinosaurs.Add("Compsognathus");

var readOnlyDinosaurs = new ReadOnlyCollection<string>(dinosaurs);
```

Comment: Exactly what I'm looking for, thank you.  I guess I haven't gotten used to how to search the MSDN site yet.

Comment: The best search for MSDN is google :) But I knew it was called ReadOnlyCollection, If you are searching for Unmodifiable list you might have less results.

Comment: The last line can be `var readonlyDinosaurs = dinosaurs.AsReadOnly()`

Comment: Note that this does not actually make the collection itself read-only. Rather, it gives you a read-only wrapper around the mutable collection; attempts to mutate the wrapper will throw exceptions, but anyone who can get a reference to the original collection can still mutate it.