# Read-Only List in C#

Tags: c#, .net, list

I have some class with `List`-property:

```
class Foo {
  private List<int> myList;
}
```

I want provide access to this field only for read.

I.e. I want property with access to Enumerable, Count, etc. and without access to Clear, Add, Remove, etc. How I can do it?

Comment: I'm going to go a head and change the title of this question to read-only because read-only and immutability are two very different albeit related topics, I'd prefer it if we did not mix them. If you're looking for immutability check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/9009748/58961.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Read-only list or unmodifiable list in .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984042/read-only-list-or-unmodifiable-list-in-net-4-0)

Comment: Starting with .NET Core 1.0 (and .NET 5), the library includes all sorts of immutable collections. See [System.Collections.Immutable Namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-6.0#classes). The difference between immutable and read-only collections in short: an instance of an immutable collection is read-only *and* unchangeable. Instances of read-only collections are wrappers that allow the owner of the wrapped collection to change it. From the consumer perspective, a read-only collection could change at any time while an immutable never will.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

If you want a read-only view of a list you could use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx).

```
class Foo {
    private ReadOnlyCollection<int> myList;
}
```

Comment: Or, more accurately, a private `List<int>` variable and a public `ReadOnlyCollection<int>` property with a `get {}` that returns the variable.

Comment: @Victor: that would give calling code access to the mutable list by a simple cast. Probably not what the OP wants. The readonly property could `return new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(myList);` though.

Comment: ReadOnlyCollection is not really immutable as it contains a pointer to the original list - if you add something to your list, the readOnly-instance can access this new item either... but, you are right, when it comes down to modifications-methods - these are missing!

Comment: @Andreas: the OP does not state that the list content must not change; the only requirement given is that the calling code must not be able to change it.

Comment: @Fredrik: this is what I meant (and expressed quite awkwardly, I admit) ;-)

Comment: @Fredrik Mörk: my comment was just for mentioning a side-effect

Comment: @FredrikMörk: because the title says "immutable". Perhaps it should be changed to "readonly".

Answer (score 84):

You can expose a `List<T>` as a `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` by using the  `AsReadOnly()` method

#### C# 6.0 and later (using [*Expression Bodied Properties*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members))

```
class Foo { 

  private List<int> myList;

  public ReadOnlyCollection<int> ReadOnlyList => myList.AsReadOnly();

}
```

#### C# 5.0 and earlier

```
class Foo {

  private List<int> myList;

  public ReadOnlyCollection<int> ReadOnlyList {
     get {
         return myList.AsReadOnly();
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice and clean, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: I think that there should be a `return` before `myList`

Answer (score 9):

i would go for

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    private readonly List<object> _items = new List<object>();

    public IEnumerable<object> Items
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (var item in this._items)
            {
                yield return item;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with the yield break at the end?

Comment: Also the Foo could implement IEnumerable

Comment: @Jon Skeet: just copy past ... at first i had a `// TODO`, but replaced it with a foreach ... thanks for that hint!

Comment: @Turek: jep, indeed ... but as not stated i did not take that into account - maybe the OP needs some more properties (lists)

Answer (score 9):

There is now an Immutable Collections library that does exactly that. Which you can install via nuget.

> The immutable collection classes are supported starting with the .NET
>   Framework 4.5.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn385366%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> The System.Collections.Immutable namespace provides generic immutable
>   collection types that you can use for these scenarios, including:
>   ImmutableArray<T>, 
>   ImmutableDictionary<Tkey,TValue>, 
>   ImmutableSortedDictionary<T>, ImmutableHashSet<T>,
>   ImmutableList<T>, ImmutableQueue<T>, ImmutableSortedSet<T>,
>   ImmutableStack<T>

Example of Usage:

```
class Foo
{
    public ImmutableList<int> myList { get; private set; }

    public Foo(IEnumerable<int> list)
    {
        myList = list.ToImmutableList();
    }
}
```

Comment: ImmutableList DOES allow you to add new elements, it just creates another list object for that.
`Note that these methods return a new object. When you add or remove items from an immutable list, a copy of the original list is made with the items added or removed, and the original list is unchanged.`
This answer shouldn't be upvoted.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi The terms "immutable" or "read-only" refer to the actual instance. *"[...] return a new object."* means "return a new instance", where the original instance remains in its original state. Distributing an accessible immutable list in fact prevents the consumer to mutate it. They will always modify a copy. A read-only collection on the other hand is not immutable as it can be modified via the underlying i.e. wrapped collection. In other words: retrieving an immutable collection instance guarantees the consumer that this instance will never change.

Comment: @AymenDaoudi This means, an instance of `ImmutableList<T>` is read-only (it implements `IReadOnlyList<T>` and *in addition* it is immutable (unchangeable). Whether the OP needs the list to be immutable or not is not stated in the question. Since I believe that it is really worth to consider to make the returned instance immutable, I find this a valid answer which gives the OP or any reader that looks for a solution regarding a similar problem a valuable choice. Hence this answer qualifies for an upvote.

Comment: `ImmutableList<T>` is available without installing additional packages. It is now included in .NET Core and .NET 5 or later. See [System.Collections.Immutable Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.immutable?view=net-6.0#classes).

Comment: @AymenDaoudi The original title of this question even explicitly asked for an immutable list.

Answer (score 3):

If you declare a readonly list in your class, you'll still be able to add items to it.

If you don't want to add or change anything, you should be using `ReadOnlyCollection<T>` as Darin suggested.

If you want to add, remove items from the list but don't want to change the content, you can use a `readonly List<T>`.