# Make list immutable

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Immutable List in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680035/immutable-list-in-c)

Is it possible to make a list immutable

Comment: [Immutable List in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680035/immutable-list-in-c)

Comment: Immutable how? Please give an example of usage.

Comment: Which list do you mean? Try it with `list.Enabled = false;` ...

Comment: Those that come across this thread without checking the duplicate may want to know that .NET Framework 4.5 introduced an `ImmutableList`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn467185(v=vs.111).aspx

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`ReadOnlyCollection<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132474.aspx) instead.

Comment: It can be wise to `var readonly = new ReadOnlyCollection<int>(new List<int>(ints));` so that you don't accidently make changes to the wrapped collection as I discovered here  http://alicebobandmallory.com/articles/2011/01/01/lazy-evaluation-is-no-friend-of-mutable-state

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>.AsReadOnly`() returns a readonly wrapper, so that you can't add/remove/replace elements.

To be truly immutable, the type T must be an immutable Type.

Comment: I thought about a `ListBox` :)