# Class property that is list<string> and should be immutable after it was populated by constructor

Tags: c#

I want to create a class named Employee in C#. It needs to have 2 strings containing first and last names and a List property that will contain previous job positions. All 3 properties should be populated through a constructor and unchangeable afterwards.

```
class Employee
{
    public string firstName { get; }
    public string lastName{ get; }
    private List<string> prevPositions;
    public Employee () {}
    public Employee (string fName, string lName, List<string> pPos)
    {
        firstName = fName;
        lastName = lName;
        prevPositions = pPos;
    }
    public IList<string> Positions
    { get {return prevPos;} }
}
```

However in my main method I can still use something like:

```
Employee fEmp = new Employee("John", "Doe", new List<string> { "junior", "senior" });
fEmp.Position.Add("CEO");
foreach (string st in fEmp.Positions)
    Console.WriteLine("Prev Positons are {0}", st);
```

And I get CEO as part of previous positions. Now I understand that this happens, due to fEmp.Position being a reference to a memory where list is stored, and thus I can use .Add to add element to the list, and my immutability goes to thrash.

Does anyone know how would I go about this?

Comment: Set your properties to readonly

Comment: @LaurentLequenne they are readonly because he only has a getter but you can add through the property

Comment: Euh yah... I'm stupid...and even if your list is readonly, you can still add some items in it :)

Comment: Not sure but you could try : private readonly string[] prevPositions;

Comment: @HimBromBeere how about going the duplicate chain one step further (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4680035/read-only-list-in-c-sharp) instead of marking as duplicate of a duplicate. I know most problems are solvable by adding another layer of indirection, but this awesome knowledge is not meant for problems that are already solved without the extra indirection :P